# Is there a library in React Native for compressing to tar and then zipping with gzip to create a tar.gz?

Tags: node.js, react-native, gzip, libraries, tar

I need to compress files to a tar.gz format in a React Native application before sending them to the backend. I found packages in Node.js for tar and there's a React Native library for gzip, but I'm not sure if there's a library that does what I need.

I found libraries for tar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar

and gzip: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gzip

but I haven't found a library for doing both in React Native

Comment: Hello @sizzle, welcome to SO. Can you please be more specific with your question & clarify the problem?

Comment: File compression is done on the backend primarily & not on the client(mobile or web/frontend) btw, so I don't undertsand why would you want to compress on mobile before sending. You could just upload files to backend & let it handle the compression, no?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Client wants the compression to be handled on the frontend before sending to the backend.

Comment: in that case, take a look at this [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-image-compressor). It does basic compression with JS. There are also other options in case you're using TS: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-image-compression) & [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin) -- also, you can a basic example on `ImageMin` [here](https://web.dev/articles/use-imagemin-to-compress-images)